# Sites think I'm from another country when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In Firefox, when I visit, for example "jinx.com" the prices are displayed in dollars ($) yet when I visit the same site in Chrome the prices are displayed in pounds (£).

This is extremely annoying and I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it, unless I'm googling the wrong thing I can't seem to find any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it... Somehow my Chrome's language was set to UK English and not US English.

I had to change the spell checker language, clear the cookies and reload Chrome, now the site is displaying in dollars instead of pounds.